# Android DownloadManager class not working mobile 4G data?

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I have developed an android application using Android DownloadManager Class. When I try to download file over WiFi working without issue but when I use mobile data downloading not working, showing waiting for network.

This is my code:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse((urlString)));
```

manifest.xml permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and this is my reference page: [Android DownloadManager example](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-DownloadManager-example.htm#)

Answer (score 2):

From what you've provided I can only recommend you to remove the unnecessary code s.a. `request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(Request.NETWORK_WIFI | Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);` because it by default allows all types of network. Also make sure you haven't set setAllowedOverMetered() and setAllowedOverRoaming() to false.

Comment: @VijilDhas -  In such case this is probably not your apps fault. Try downloading something from the internet on 4G using chrome, is it working or giving the same error? Also, make sure to provide the error code in your question.

Comment: from my experience, it also affected by android built-in network connectivty check result. simply, if you see a exclamation mark in you wifi singal indicator or a 'x' on the mobile singal. the system download service will not work until exclamation mark dismissed.